# XCode IPhone Simulator doesnt show user location after upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, location, mapkit, xcode4.4

I was working with XCode 4.3 and having a working code. But after upgrading to 4.4 i met with a problem. The problem is that current user location is not being showed on the iphone simulator. I mean the blue dot. And also my pins dissappeared and map is not focusing to the area i wanted. Do u have any idea about this problem?

Comment: have you enabled "Simulate User Location"?

Comment: I am selecting some locations as I was doing like london, paris or my custom location. before, it was moving immediately. now im only seeing default america continents on the map. no movement, no pins, no blue dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
```

Comment: yes I did. the problem is it was showing the blue dot and focusing to the area i wanted. after upgrading xcode from 4.3 to 4.4, the blue dot dissappeared and it is not focusing. I am only seeing the continents of america on the map and there is no compilation error.

Comment: that means your map is not even updating to current location?

Comment: I think the problem is mapkit is not working properly. Coz after I put "self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;" in viewdidload, blue dot worked. But thats not logic. My working code was in  "(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:"  function. now i cant see my annotations, no area focus no blue dot.

Comment: in the didUpdateToLocation:  method print the value of the latitude and longitude and see if its updating?

Comment: Im selecting paris, london or my custom location and the function is not even triggered. there is no blue dot.

Comment: [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; did you call this method? did you set the necessary delegates?

Comment: it was working all fine 2 hours ago. and my previous versions were working. Now everything works fine except location services. especially mkmapview method seems to be not working. but the interesting thing is there is no compilation error..

Comment: ok lets check everything. you added the <MapKit/MapKit.h> <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h> <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>, you added delegates <MKMapViewDelegate,MKAnnotation,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Comment: it would be easier to help you if i could see more of ur code

Comment: Btw, if you didn't know it, simulator doesnt not find ur actual location, it shows the location that is set in => open your simulator and on the top bar click debug=>Location=>custom location

Comment: custom location is already set. do u think it is a code problem? coz after I select simulator location from default locations in xcode, it doesnt even show blue dot. i do select moscow, london, paris etc but no blue dot on that cities..

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device? Then we'll know if there is any point fiddling with the settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

GPS services doesn't work well in simulator. Apple has supported it in simulator 5 but not in the prior versions.

Comment: should i remove 4.4 and install 4.3 back?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Edit Scheme... > Run > Options the 'Allow Location Simulation' checked.

I also had the issue at first. Pin was there but no map displayed, only a grid.

I played with the map to move it around and it start working.

I have xcode 7.3.1